# Can we purchase addon to increase limits on SingleEmail Apex limits?

Tags: apex, email, limits

The number of emails(using `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage`) we can send using Apex per day per org is 5000.

There is a workaround to send emails using workflow but it won't solve our need as it won't add activity history on the record.

We are in the early stages of developing our Salesforce application and this really helps if we can buy extra limits. Any idea on this?

Screenshot showing the actual limits I am talking about:

[image]

**NOTE**: I have looked into all other questions related to email limits and I didn't see anything that says if we can purchase more emails.

Comment: Note this limit does not apply when sending the email to a User via `TargetObjectId`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can request additional emails per day, as outlined in [Help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334435&type=1&mode=1). You cannot *purchase* additional emails per day, but if you have a strong business purpose, you can have it increased temporarily or permanently.

Note that:

> We will not approve increase requests for Marketing purposes (New Product or Service Notifications, Sales Follow Ups, and so on).
>
> ...
>
> We will consider realistic requests for emergency scenarios for organizations with a high number of User Licenses (for example: Product or Service Outages or Emergency Customer Communications).
>
> ...
>
> Requests are only considered for Production organizations. We will not raise this limit for Sandboxes under any circumstances.
>
> ...
>
> If an indefinite increase is requested, please be prepared to provide an extremely strong business reason to accompany the request.

*(**NOTE:** There are additional caveats; please read the Help topic carefully.)*

Answer (score 3):

Re: "There is a workaround to send emails using workflow but it won't solve our need as it won't add activity history on the record."

You could just set up the Process Builder or Workflow Rule to also create an activity on the same record. This is pretty commonplace.

But overall Salesforce does not see their CRM as a mass email system. If it's what you need to do then you should be looking at something third-party to help with it.

Comment: This really helped me. I did bit more research after your answer on the available workarounds and we decided to go with Workflows to send emails and log activity on the actual record in the form of EmailMessage so that users know when the email was sent with what content and etc.